# Time synchronization between 2 android devices

Tags: android, timestamp

i have read so many synchronization protocols for wireless sensor network which removes the effect of clock offset and clock drift between two nodes..i want to implement it on an android device,Is is possible? I need your valuable answer as soon as possible..thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you consider Android phones simply as nodes connected by a network, then the answer is rather easy;

Yes, it is possible.

It might be very challenging though. But in general, the theory behind distributed time synchronisation is not limited to special types of nodes or networks.

The exact type of nodes and network will have an impact on what algorithm fits best, and how it performs.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey your answer but in my case these two devices are not connected with the other network. I just want to send time of one phone's clock to the 2nd one so that 2nd one can set it's time according to 1st one. And I want to get accuracy of minimum 100 microsecond.Also I am new to android and want to know Is it possible to get time-stamp at the MAC layer(when packets are about to transmit)? Thanks once again :)

Comment: You will never hit that accuracy. You simply don't have low level control.